# Watching a function

Tags: javascript, watch

In javascript I know we can watch for a property change, but is it possible to watch a function?

If I had a function that evaluates to a boolen

```
function eval(value) {
    return value == 1;
}
```

Would it be possible to continuously evaluate this function until true?

I know setTimeout could work, but that seems like a hack. Is there a better way?

Comment: that is the only way.

Comment: *"...possible to watch a function?"* Watch it do what? Are you expecting the *function* to change, or its return value? (E.g., because its return value is based on something it closes over.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by watch, Maybe you should be more specific or provide a use case. There are frameworks like angular and knockout for "watching" function/variables values. You could also look at [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#compact) function section. it might help.

Comment: What do you understand as "continously"? An infinite loop probably won't work…

Comment: What `value` would you want to pass in?

Comment: change the function name! It will cause ambiguity I suppose

Comment: I don't quite get what exactly what you are trying to do, but if you can watch a property, why not assign value to a watched property and evaluate it from there instead of passing it to a function as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main possible ways, the first is yours, the setTimeout. The second is a setInterval:

```
var checkEval = setInterval(function(){eval(value)},1000);
```

And you could end it using:

```
clearInterval(checkEval);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the function with a wrapper

```
function something(){
   return value==1;
}

(function(window){
  var oldSomething = window.something;
  window.something = function(){
     var result = oldSomething.apply(null,arguments);
     if(result===true){
        //do what you need
     } 
     return result;
  };
})(window);
```